# Can I use dll library which compiled in Qt 5.12 with MSVC 2017 in Qt 5.5 MSVC 2010 project

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, compiler-warnings

What is the affect of compiler versions about using projects each other? Can I use dll library which compiled in Qt 5.12 with MSVC 2017 in Qt 5.5 MSVC 2010 project.

Answer (score 0):

No, only the other way round. Qt is backward compatible but not forward (how it should be)

Comment: Ok assume that qt versions are same. What about compiler version. dll compiled in mscv 2017 and my project which referenced dll compiling mscv 2010. @chehrlic

Comment: msvc2010 and 2017 are not ABI compatible. Only 2017 and 2019 is.